# Increase Trackpoint Speed of ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, usb, thinkpad

Setting the `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` property to < 0.2 with `xinput` kind of did the trick, but for me it also killed the preciseness and smoothness of the cursor.

Is there any way I can increase the trackpoint speed of [Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd026745) on a lower level?

I tried to look for something similar to built-in keyboard's trackpoint speed config `/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/speed`

However, in my USB keyboard's corresponding directory `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:17EF:6047.0002` I found only these:

`country  fn_lock  input  power  sensitivity  uevent   driver   hidraw   modalias  report_descriptor  subsystem`

I also gave [tpkbdctl](https://github.com/hiikezoe/tpkbdctl) a shot but it didn't seem to have any effect.

My kernel version is 4.8.8-1-ARCH

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the xipnut prop `Device Accel Profile` for the device? https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/ have decent information about pointer speed/acceleration configuration

Comment: @chenaren Hi, I'm facing the exact same problem. Have you solved it?